# PyQt Sort List of Radio Buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, radio-button, pyqt

I am trying to dynamically create a list of radio buttons that represents the open COM ports on my computer.  Creating and displaying the list the first time is easy enough since I can just sort the ports to be in numerical order and then add their corresponding radio button to my vertical layout.

However, if the user inserts a new device which creates a new COM port, I have to find some way to add the new button in the correct place since it might not be in the right numerical order. So far, the only way I have been able to do this is to just get rid of all the buttons and then re-add them after sorting the list since addWidget doesn't let me specify where to add the widget.  This method seems really inefficient, and I am assuming there is a simpler way, but I just have not found it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `addWidget()`, determine the index in the list of buttons to place the new one, and use `QBoxLayout.insertWidget(index, widget)` to insert it there:

```
newButton = QRadioButton(...)
newText = newButton.text()

index = 0
for button in get_buttons():
    if button.text() >= newText:
      break
    index += 1

layout.insertWidget(index, newButton)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out.  Do you know what would happen if I tried to insert a button with an index higher than the number of "boxes" the layout has created? For example, if ports 1,2,3, and 10 are open could I do something like `layout.insertWidget(10, com10button)` without that creating empty boxes between buttons 3 and 10?

Comment: Just got everything working how I want it to.  I used the bisect module to determine the index instead of having to write my own loop to determine the index since the order is based off of an integer.

Comment: @gwenger: Good point.  If your list is always sorted using an integral reference value, the `bisect` module is the way to go.